# Extra clauses with a CTE and Geopgraphy datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, geolocation, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlgeography

I'm creating a query to match based on distance people using zip codes using the Geography datatype in SQL Server. I have it 99% there, but I have two problems. At the moment, this searches by zip, city and state, but I also need to match on [u.username] really. I can't get the syntax right to add an "OR Username LIKE @Name". Secondly, the performance isn't great. With 21 test users from all over the US, the query takes 4 seconds.

Is there a way to speed this up and add the extra search parameters. I have this so far:

```
DECLARE @miles [float] = 10000;
DECLARE @myposition geography;
SELECT @myposition = GeoLocation FROM ZipCodes
WHERE Zip LIKE '11204';

SELECT z.*,z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) AS Distance INTO #HASHTABLE FROM ZipCodes z
WHERE z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) <= (@miles*1609.344)
ORDER BY Distance asc

;WITH Results_CTE AS (SELECT u.*,z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) AS Distance, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition)) AS RowNum
FROM Users u INNER JOIN ZipCodes z ON u.PostCode = z.Zip
WHERE u.PostCode in (SELECT Zip from #hashtable) OR u.City in (SELECT City from #hashtable) 
) SELECT * FROM Results_CTE WHERE RowNum > 0 
DROP TABLE #Hashtable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @cipx, but I found that your suggestion actually returned duplicates. After looking at this with fresh eyes, I seem to have a way to search on multiple fields with AND or OR.

```
DECLARE @miles [float] = 100;
DECLARE @myposition geography;
SELECT @myposition = GeoLocation FROM ZipCodes
WHERE Zip LIKE '28790'; --OR city like 'brooklyn';--'11204';

SELECT z.*,z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) AS Distance INTO #HASHTABLE FROM ZipCodes z
WHERE z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) <= (@miles*1609.344)
ORDER BY Distance asc

;WITH Results_CTE AS (SELECT u.*,z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) AS Distance, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition), userid) AS RowNum
FROM Users u INNER JOIN ZipCodes z ON u.PostCode = z.Zip
WHERE 
-- Using zip code and distance
-- u.PostCode in (SELECT Zip from #hashtable) 

-- using a link table to find users skilled in wrestling
-- OR UserID IN (SELECT UserID from UserSkills us INNER JOIN Skills s ON us.SkillID = s.SkillID WHERE s.Name LIKE 'wrestlin%') 

-- scalar properties of the UserProfiles table
-- DisplayName like 'johnny%'
) SELECT * FROM Results_CTE WHERE RowNum > 0 
DROP TABLE #Hashtable
```

This gives me paging and querying over 300 users on a few different fields in about a second, which isn't great but it's acceptable for now.

Answer (score 1):

do you have any indexes declared? I would renounce on the temporary table and write the below query, also add a few indexes: on ZipCodes table (a spatial index on GeoLocation column), and on users table (on City and Zip column).

```
DECLARE @miles [float] = 10000;
DECLARE @myposition geography;
SELECT @myposition = GeoLocation FROM ZipCodes
WHERE Zip LIKE '11204';

SELECT u.*,z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) as Distance from Users u
INNER JOIN ZipCodes z ON u.PostCode = z.Zip
WHERE
    z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) <= (@miles*1609.344)
AND
    u.Username LIKE '%'+@Name+'%'

UNION

SELECT u.*,z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) as Distance from Users u
INNER JOIN ZipCodes z ON u.City = z.City
WHERE
    z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition) <= (@miles*1609.344)
AND
    u.Username LIKE '%'+@Name+'%'

ORDER BY
    z.GeoLocation.STDistance(@myposition)
```

Comment: Yes, I have indexes on city,state,zip, lat, long and lat/lng. I'll give this a try though. Thanks.